# Sample printf implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, formatting, variadic

Here is my code for `printf()` implementation in C. Please share your thoughts for improvements.

```
#define PRINTCHAR(c) putchar(c)
#define MAXLEN 256

// Write a printf function which simulates printf() in C.
int formatAndPrintString(char *pcFmt, va_list lList)
{
    //Holds the number of characters printed, 0 on error
    int nChars = 0;

while(*pcFmt != '\0')
{
    if(*pcFmt == '%')
    {
        pcFmt++;

        int iTemp = 0;
        char acTemp[MAXLEN] = ""; 
        char *pcTemp = NULL, cTemp = 0;

        switch (*pcFmt)
        {
        case 'd':
            iTemp = va_arg(lList, int);
            itoa(iTemp, acTemp, 10); 

            for(int i = 0; i < strlen(acTemp); i++)
            {
                PRINTCHAR(acTemp[i]); nChars++;
            }
            break;
        case 's':
            pcTemp = va_arg(lList, char*);

            while(*pcTemp != '\0')
            {
                PRINTCHAR(*pcTemp); nChars++;
                pcTemp++;
            }
            break;
        case 'c':
            cTemp = va_arg(lList, int);  
            PRINTCHAR(cTemp);
            nChars++;
            break;
       default:
          break;
       }
       pcFmt++;
    }
    else 
    // print the char to console
    {
       PRINTCHAR(*pcFmt);
       pcFmt++; nChars++;
    }
}
return nChars;
}

// Print function identical to printf() in stdio.h
int printfunc(char *pcFormat, ...)
{
    if(!pcFormat)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    va_list lList;
    va_start(lList, pcFormat);

    return(formatAndPrintString(pcFormat, lList));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

### Bugs

#### There is no call to `va_end()`

> ```
>  The va_start() macro must be called first, and it initializes ap, which can be passed to va_arg() for each argument to be processed.  Calling
>  va_end() signals that there are no further arguments, and causes ap to be invalidated.  Note **that each call to va_start() must be matched by a
>  call to va_end(), from within the same function**.
> ```

#### `Char` and `Int` do not have the same size.

This advice was wrong:

```
    case 'c':
        cTemp = va_arg(lList, int);
```

I am surprised this passes your unit tests. It will read a value off the parameter list but also advance it `sizeof(int)` places. While a character is only of length `sizeof(char)`.

```
Note  sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)
      sizeof(char) == 1
```

I am going to leave the above in (because it is a learning experience for me).

From:  @PeteBecker [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) Section:  6.5.2.2/7

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.**

Thus the `char` argument is promoted to `int` when effectively pushed to the stack. So you need to use int when reading it from the var args list. Thus the code is correct.

#### Unchecked increment:

```
 default:
          break;
       }
       pcFmt++;
```

Pretty sure this would break if I used the string "%"

### Notes:

Whenever you call `PRINTCHAR()` you also execute `nChars++;` so why not put both into the same functioin.

### Extensions you should add in the long run.

#### You cover the bare minimum

You have format d/s/c but in printf there are a lot more with a lot more options: nore Types, type Extension (long/short), width, more formatting, etc.

#### No Locale Coverage

Output printing is affected a lot by current locale.

Comment: agreed it will break in the default case, and I implemented 3 basic formats(s,d,c) to begin with,your feedback again much appreciated,tried to implement with straight and clean approach

Comment: If `char` is smaller than `int` (that's not required: `char` can be large) then `char` arguments are promoted to `int` when passed through an ellipsis. So the use of `va_arg(lList, int)` for `'c'`, while unintuitive, is correct.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You have a reference for that?

Comment: Read about "default promotions".

Comment: @PeteBecker: I am aware of the default promotions. But why is the compiler promoting types when it knows the types. Do you have something about `va_arg()` or about placing things on the stack when elipses are involved that shows that they will be promoted.

Comment: C99, C11: 6.5.2.2/7.

Answer (score 8):

Going from case `'d'` to case `'c'`, you have these lines:

`'d'`:

```
PRINTCHAR(acTemp[i]); nChars++;
```

`'s'`:

```
PRINTCHAR(*pcTemp); nChars++;
```

`'c'`:

```
PRINTCHAR(cTemp);
nChars++;
```

Why did you all of a sudden change the pattern? In my opinion, you should be using the pattern that you used in option `'c'` because it is clean and spread out, rather than jammed into one line.

---

Your `while` loop looks a lot like a `for` loop:

```
while(*pcFmt != '\0')
{
    ...
        pcFmt++;
```

I recommend changing it to a `for` loop so all the components of the loop are easily seen together in the signature of the loop:

```
for(; *pcFmt != '\0'; pcFmt++)
```

Also, from the code that I've seen that iterates through the characters of a string, this way (as I have shown) is more common.

---

Your indentation is really off.

That `while` loop and everything inside of should be indented because it is inside a function. And, the case statements inside your `switch` should, too, be indented.

---

I'm not sure if you gave yourself a requirement to not use *any* string printing functions, but these lines:

```
while(*pcTemp != '\0')
{
    PRINTCHAR(*pcTemp); nChars++;
    pcTemp++;
}
```

could be shortened to

```
puts(pcTemp);
```

The `puts` function is a built in function that just comes with the C compiler; no `<stdio.h>` needed.

---

Comment: Thanks @SirPython, for in case of while loop and puts() call against putchar() is much appreciated,will use that,tried to maintain a straightforward approach to the problem

Answer (score 7):

### Termination expression

I have a pet peeve when people use functions/expressions in their termination clause which have constant value:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(acTemp); i++)
```

Here you are going to call `strlen` N times, making this loop an \$O(n^2)\$ loop for no reason.  Much better would be:

```
        int len = strlen(acTemp);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

I just did a check and `gcc -O3` is smart enough to optimize that loop for you.  But there will come a time where it won't be able to do that because instead of `strlen` you will have a function that the compiler doesn't recognize, and it will be forced to call that function N times.

Comment: I think GCC and Clang are always able to fix the mistake of calling `strlen` repeatedly with the same input because in their implementation the function is marked with [`__attribute__((pure))`,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) so redundant calls can be eliminated in the common subexpression removal step. Nevertheless, your answer is valid. The OP could very well be calling some user defined function inside the loop instead, that the compiler could not be able to optimize.